# Javascript optgroup[label=] with special character

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, optgroup

I have a problem with javascript for an Oracle APEX Report and I cant find the answer.

Im trying to do:

```
prompt($('#obs_ir_oot_objecten_saved_reports optgroup[label="Priv\é"] option').length);
```

This results in 0
But the optgroup has options in it

```
<optgroup label="Privé">
 <option value="19580268757611765">1. Test</option>
 <option value="19596594240127860">2. Test G</option>
 <option value="19580521094630982">3. Test 1</option>
 <option value="19581084888635942">4. Test 2</option>
 <option value="19585119906724784">5. Test 3</option>
</optgroup>
```

Other optgroups with out a special characters work fine using a \ or not before the é makes no difference.
A I missing something? I hope somebody knows the answer.

Comment: I would tag this with jquery -the fact that you're doing this in APEX isn't relevant to this problem. For me this works ok both escaped and unescaped. Are you sure the "é" in your html and the "é" in the javascript is the same character ?

Comment: or you could use the contains operator and skip that special character - optgroup[label*="Priv"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

optgroup[label*="Priv"] solved the problem.

Thank you.